# C++ read from formatted .txt file

Tags: c++, stream

I need to read in from a comma-separated .txt file where each line looks something this:

> 1234,0987,Bob,23.45

(ie int,int,string,double)

using the following setup code:

```
fstream myFile;
myFile.open("textfile.txt" , ios::in);
if (myFile.is_open()) {
    //read in characters as appropriate type until ','
}
```

I have tried using

```
myFile >> int1 ......
```

but I was unsure how I should deal with the commas; they may get filtered out when reading in integers, but would that work when I get to the string?

one of my classmates suggested stringstream, but i've found the documentation on cplusplus.com to be over my head.

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) takes a delimiter. You could play with that. It might not be the most elegant method I can think of, but for a "C++ newbie", it should be possible to play around with.

Comment: Read into string and then parse, or use strtok and then parse into values, or use sscanf, or use regex, or something else...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+read+from+comma+delimited+file

Comment: thanks guys, got it compiling. doesn't work, but that's all on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try out the `std::getline` function:

```
istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str, char delim );
istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str );
```

(From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/)